# I am trying to understand the meaning of prendi

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, single-words

I know that prendi means ‘take’ but I am wondering what it would mean in this context.

Tu, vieni qui, prendi casa?

It also seems it can be used in other ways?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Could you please give some more context?

Comment: If someone was deciding what to do and mentioning wanting to visit someone’s house and the person responded telling them it’s not interesting then said that. All with a slightly romantic sub context ;-)

Comment: Do you mean that they are not interested? In any case, the Italian sentence doesn't seem to have anything to do with such a scenario. _Prendi casa_ is a way of saying “you begin to live somewhere” or “you rent/buy a house”. Are you sure you understood correctly?

Comment: Comment by @Andrej: Could you please provide the citation from which this sentence comes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sentence is a bit weird, but in this context it should mean "You should come (move in) here and rent (or buy!) an apartment (or house). It has nothing to do with visiting anyone. "Prendere" can have several meanings depending on the context, among them to buy, rent or order. "Casa" can stand for "house", but also "home", so, the sentence has indeed somewhat romantic and poetic tone, but the explanation of the context you provided is way off.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: @Andrej the question at the end of the answer should be removed from there and posted as comment under the question.

Comment: Grazie per la spiegazione abarisone. Ho rimosso la domanda dalla risposta, ma sembra che la mia reputazione sia ancora troppo bassa per poter scrivere nei commenti.

Comment: @abarisone: I have done it.